# SQL intersect two joined tables

Tags: sql, join, intersect

I joined two tables

```
SELECT 
    t1.column1, 
    t2.column2  
FROM 
    t1 JOIN t2 cu 
        ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.col LIKE 'A%'  



SELECT
    t1.column1, 
    t2.column2  
FROM
    t1 JOIN t2 cu 
        ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.col LIKE 'B%'
```

How could i intersect these tables so I can have the following output (ids that have both the A% and B%)

**join 1**

```
id | col
---┼------
1  | Axxxx
2  | Axxxx
```

**join 2**

```
id | col
---┼-------
1  | Bxxxx
3  | Bxxxx
```

**Final output**

```
id | col
---┼-------
1  | Axxxx
1  | Bxxxx
```

Thank you

Comment: Put the queries in sub-queries and join them together

Comment: Could you please give a small example/template, HoneyBadger, I'm a beginner in SQL :(

Comment: Which db ...? please

Comment: You want the rows from both the tables having the same id? Mandatory with intersect or is the result your goal..?

Comment: the table are within the same database and basicaly yes, ids that have col both like A% and B%

Comment: How can select1 and select2 both return id = 1?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, ...?

Comment: The DB is SQL and they have the same id because there were 2 tables with id as a fk that were joined.
Now I have to intersect them and get the ids that have col both as A% and B%

Comment: SQL is a language not a DBMS. What product (e.g. MySQL or SQL Server or Oracle) are you using?

Comment: Please update your example to make it more plausible. An ID uniquely identifies a record in a table. It is highly unlikely to have two tables the IDs of which are related (as in `ON t1.id = t2.id`). Also please show queries that match your sample data (`id` vs. `column1`).

Comment: Can you add sample table data also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, and what you want is only the ID's that have both A% and B%, then this is your answer

```
SELECT 
t1.column1, 
t2.column2  
FROM 
t1 JOIN t2 cu 
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND ((t1.col LIKE 'A%'  AND t2.col like 'B%')
    OR (t1.col LIKE 'B%' AND t2.col like 'A%'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample you don't need intersect but a simple union

```
 SELECT 
  t1.column1, 
  t2.column2  
FROM 
  t1 JOIN t2 cu 
      ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.col LIKE 'A%'  

union

SELECT
  t1.column1, 
  t2.column2  
FROM
  t1 JOIN t2 cu 
      ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.col LIKE 'B%'
```

adapt the sintax for union at your db/sql

Answer (score 1):

Also try it this way ... as you are looking for only repeatable IDs ... you could just count them from inner select

```
select column1, column2 from (
     select column1, column2, count(column1) over (partition by column1) [Counted] from (
        SELECT 
           t1.column1, 
           t2.column2  
        FROM 
        t1 JOIN t2 cu 
            ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.col LIKE 'A%'
     UNION
        SELECT
           t1.column1, 
           t2.column2  
        FROM
           t1 JOIN t2 cu 
           ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.col LIKE 'B%' 
    ) src
) src2 where Counted > 1
```